# Getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I executed the following code

```
Map<String, SyncPrimitive> syncPrimitives = new HashMap<String, SyncPrimitive>();

for (SyncPrimitive primitive : this.getSyncPrimitives()) {
         String groupId = primitive.getId();
         primitive.onConnect(groupId);
    }
```

Then I' getting the following exception

```
Error while calling watcher 
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)
```

In the onConnect method the primitive oject is modified. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Show your onConnect method.

Comment: Map take <K,V> does this code compile ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could not modify collection during iteration it with for-each. If you want to modify it, use [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

This kind of exceptions pretty clear described [in documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>
> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances.

### See related questions:

- [How to modify a Collection while iterating using for-each loop without ConcurrentModificationException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958478/modifying-a-collection-while-iterating-using-for-each-loop)
- [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection)
- [Java: adding elements to a collection during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/java-adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration)