# Deleting and adding objects to list while iterating

Tags: java, listiterator

I am trying to remove objects from a list and I get the following exception :

```
failure:java.util.ConcurrentModificationException null
```

And this is how I try to remove the objects from the list:

```
private List<testVO> removeDuplicateEntries(List<testVO> sessionList,List<testVO> dbList){


        for (Iterator<testVO> dbIterator = dbList.listIterator(); dbIterator.hasNext(); ) {
            testVO voDB = dbIterator.next();

            for (Iterator<testVO> sessionIterator = sessionList.iterator(); sessionIterator.hasNext();) {
                testVO voSession = (testVO) sessionIterator.next();

                if(voDB.getQuestionID().intValue() == voSession.getQuestionID().intValue()){
                    //remove the object from sesion list
                    sessionIterator.remove();
                    //Add the object from DB to session list
                    sessionList.add(voDB);
                }

            }

        }

        return sessionList;
    }
```

I would like to remove the duplicates which are currently in `sessionList` and add the ones from `dbList`.

Comment: Why do you add to `sessionList` inside the iterated loop?

Comment: i think nesting is causing this exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6958508/3898076

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add to the sessionList on iterating through it.

```
    for (Iterator<testVO> dbIterator = dbList.listIterator(); dbIterator.hasNext(); ) {
        testVO voDB = dbIterator.next();

        List<testVO> toBeAdded = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Iterator<testVO> sessionIterator = sessionList.iterator(); sessionIterator.hasNext();) {
            testVO voSession = (testVO) sessionIterator.next();

            if(voDB.getQuestionID().intValue() == voSession.getQuestionID().intValue()){
                //remove the object from sesion list
                sessionIterator.remove();
                //Add the object from DB to session list
                //CANNOT DO: sessionList.add(voDB);
                toBeAdded.add(voDB);
            }
        }
        Collections.addAll(sessionList, toBeAdded);
    }
```

Comment: (@Dariusz has a better usage of addAll.)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<testVO> toRemove = ...
List<testVO> toAdd = ...

// in loop
toRemove.add(removed);
toAdd.add(added);

//after appropraite loops
yourList.addAll(toAdd);
yourList.removeAll(toRemove);
```

the `toRemove` is added here in case one is using for-each version of the for loop; it is better to remove an element from collection through iterator, since it does not consume any more resources for searches.

Comment: Adding is easy, but removing is hard - each item has to be searched for linearly as there is no indication where it may be. It's better to remove when the item is actually found - using the Iterator.

Answer (score 1):

As was explained in other answers, you can't add to the collection while iterating it. You have to do the modification of information using the iterator itself - or wait until you finish iterating.

However, a plain `Iterator` just allows you to remove items. Using a `ListIterator` you can also *add* to the list. Thus, if you use `sessionList.listIterator()` rather than `sessionList.iterator()`, you'll be able to add the item while you iterate.

This has a different result than adding to the list (if that was possible), though. Suppose you have a list:

```
[ A, B, C, D, E ]
```

And you wanted to replace `C` with `c` and `D` with `d`. If you use the list iterator, your result will be:

```
[ A, B, c, d, E ]
```

While adding the items to the list would result in:

```
[ A, B, E, c, d ]
```

So, if you want the items to be appended to the end, you should do as other answers have pointed, collect all the items you want to add, and `addAll` when you finish iterating `sessionList`.

But if you want to replace them **in place** (`[ A, B, c, d, E ]`), you can use the list iterator:

```
for (ListIterator<testVO> sessionIterator = sessionList.listIterator(); sessionIterator.hasNext();) {
    testVO voSession = (testVO) sessionIterator.next();

    if(voDB.getQuestionID().intValue() == voSession.getQuestionID().intValue()){
        //remove the object from sesion list
        sessionIterator.remove();
        //Add the object from DB to the session list 
        sessionIterator.add(voDB);
    }

}
```

The differences is that `sessionIterator` is now declared as a `ListIterator` and initialized with `sessionList.listIterator()`, and also that instead of `sessionList.add()` you are using `sessionIterator.add()`.

Note that the `add` operation on `ListIterator` is optional, so, depending on the list implementation, this method may not work and throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.