# To assign Country in Country List one by one to Player in PlayerList

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am implementing RISK/Conquer game in JAVA. During the start-up phase of the game, I have to assign countries to each and every player. Just like distributing of cards from deck one by one to each player in the round-robin fashion.

The relation between Country and Player :

One Country has One Player (One to One)

One Player has Many Country (One to Many)

So far, this is my code:

**Player.java**

```
public class Player {

    public String name;
    public int totalArmies;
    public List<Country> assignedCountries;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getTotalArmies() {
        return totalArmies;
    }

    public void setTotalArmies(int totalArmies) {
        this.totalArmies = totalArmies;
    }

    public List<Country> getAssignedCountries() {
        return assignedCountries;
    }

    public void setAssignedCountries(List<Country> assignedCountries) {
        this.assignedCountries = assignedCountries;
    }


    public Player(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**startup.java**

```
 public class startup {
        HashMap<Country, List<Country>> graphMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Country> neigNodesList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Country> neigNodesList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        static List<Country> listofCountrytoAssignPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
        static List<Player> player = new ArrayList<>();
    public  void startup() {

            Country neig1 = new Country("ABC", 13, 14, "Asia");
            neigNodesList.add(neig1);
            Country neig2 = new Country("XYZ", 13, 14, "Asia");
            neigNodesList.add(neig2);

            Country country1 = new Country("MNP", 10, 11, "NorthAmerica");
            Country country2 = new Country("QWERTY", 10, 11, "NorthAmerica");
            Country country3 = new Country("IJK", 10, 11, "NorthAmerica");



            graphMap.put(country1, neigNodesList);
            graphMap.put(country2, neigNodesList1);
            graphMap.put(country3, neigNodesList);


            Iterator it = graphMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                Country keyCountry = (Country) pair.getKey();
                listofCountrytoAssignPlayers.add(keyCountry);
                List<Country> neiCountryList = (List<Country>) pair.getValue();
                System.out.println("Country -->" + keyCountry.getCountryName());
                System.out.print("------Neigh List--------");
                System.out.println(graphMap.size());

                for (Country county : neiCountryList) {
                    System.out.println(county.getCountryName());
                }
                System.out.println("-----------");


            }// avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            startup s1= new startup();
            s1.startup();
            System.out.println("Enter number of players:  ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int totalPlayers = scanner.nextInt();
            List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
            int i = 0;
            while (i < totalPlayers) {
                playerList.add(new Player("player" + i));
                i++;
            }

            Collections.shuffle(listofCountrytoAssignPlayers);
            for(Player player:playerList){
                List<Country> countryforaPlayer = new ArrayList<>();
                 for(int k=0;k<playerList.size();k++)
                 {
                    countryforaPlayer.add(listofCountrytoAssignPlayers.get(k));
                 }
                 //player.setAssignedCountries(countryforaPlayer);
                 playerList.add(player);
            }
        }

    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Enter number of players:  
1
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at startupphase.startup.main(startup.java:86)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What I am not getting is how to implement it, every algorithm/logic think of and try to implement it I am not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are modifying the collection (playerList) in the same loop, you are getting this ConcurrentModificationException.

Please go through this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958478/how-to-modify-a-collection-while-iterating-using-for-each-loop-without-concurren).
You need to use

> ListIterator

if you want to add any element in the same loop.